# Why isn't $\{1,2,3\}$ well ordered?

Tags: mathematics, textbook-and-exercises

I was reading the book "Quantum Computing Since Democritus".

> "The set of ordinal numbers has the important property of being well
> ordered,which means that every subset has a minimum element. This is
> unlike the integers or the positive real numbers, where any element
> has another that comes before it."

Unlike integers? Let's consider a set $\{1,2,3\}$ This has a minimum element.

What does the author want to say here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to math.SE

Comment: Agreed; this question is reasonable, well-motivated, and well-formulated, but the connection to quantum computing is tenuous.  It might be a good fit for math.stackexchange -[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/); it's recommended to ask the question there.

Comment: I agree that MSE is a better home for this question. BTW: I just noticed that the title asks a different question than the body of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ordered set $X$ is [well-ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) if *every* non-empty subset of $X$ has a least element.

As stated in the quote, the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers is not well-ordered (under the usual order relation). An example of a subset of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ which fails to have a least element is

$$
\{\dots, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0\},
$$

another is $\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

The set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is well-ordered since all seven non-empty subsets of it have a least element. Note that the quote does not deny well-ordering of $\{1, 2, 3\}$.